# How can I access a static resource under webapp from a JUnit test?

Tags: java, web-applications, maven-2, junit

I wrote a JUnit test that validates the xml returned by a service against its XSD. I initially put the XSD under `src/main/resrouces/xsd/<filename>.xsd` But now I'm facing the need to move it under `webapp`, as a static resource, so that it will be publicly accessible when the application is deployed.

I'd rather not have two copies, as I expect that somebody will modify the wrong one sooner or later.

I was loading the file with `getClass().getResource("/xsd/<filename>.xsd")`, how would I access it if the resource is moved under `webapp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your pom add it as a resource directory.

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>xsd/schema.xsd</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

In java use

```
String path = "/xsd/schema.xsd";
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
```

Comment: I haven't tested this because I went to another route eventually, but I suppose it will work.

Answer (score 5):

`/src/main/webapp` contents are placed on the CLASSPATH when WAR is created and deployed, but not during JUnit tests (both in maven and in my IDE). You have to load them explicitly using:

```
new File("src/main/webapp/xsd/<filename>.xsd");
```

This should work as long as project main directory is the current directory while running tests. Sad but true.

Answer (score 0):

Your resource will still remain on the classpath, so normally loading it the way you now do should keep working.